# Facebook Image Links

Tags: php, image, facebook

I am using the following code to link to an image on Facebook:

```
foreach($photos["data"] as $photo)
        {echo $photo['source'];
                echo "<img src=’{$photo['source']}’ />", "<br />";
        }
```

The echo $photo['source'] shows the correct URL, and so does the src= in the image tag, but it tries to load from my site. So:

```
If the path to the image is http://a1.myimagepath.jpg

It tries to load http://www.mysite.com/%E2%80%99http://a1.myimagepath.jpg
```

take care,
lee

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains curly quotes. You need to replace them with single quotes.

```
foreach($photos["data"] as $photo)
    {echo $photo['source'];
            echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to post the URL manually:

```
foreach ($photos["data"] as $photo) {echo $photo['source'];
    echo "<img src=’http://a1.myimagepath.jpg’ />", "<br />";
}
```

You can also try without the `foreach`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the formatting FAQ, and consider using capitalisation and punctuation to make your posts more legible. Thanks.